# SharedRDD code for ignite works on setup of single server but fails with exception when additional server added

Tags: ignite

I have 2 server nodes running collocated with spark worker. I am using shared ignite RDD to save my dataframe. My code works fine when I work with only one server node stared, if I start both server nodes code fails with

**Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [gridName=null, state=STOPPING]**

DiscoverySpi is configured as below

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">

                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
           <property name="shared" value="true"/>

                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>v-in-spark-01:47500..47509</value>
            <value>v-in-spark-02:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
</property>
```

I know this exception generally means ignite instanace either not started or stopped and operation tried with same, but I don't think this is the case for reasons that with single server node it works fine and also I am not explicitly closing ignite instance in my program.

Also in my code flow I do perform operations in transaction which works, so it is like

1. create cache1 : works fine
2. Create cache2 : works fine
3. put value in cache1 ; works fine
4. igniteRDD.saveValues on cache2 : This step failes with above mentioned exception.

[**USE this link for complete error trace**](http://pastebin.com/raw/EzzKE5mU)
caused by part is pasted below here also

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [gridName=null, state=STOPPING]
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.illegalState(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:190)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.readLock(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:90)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.guard(IgniteKernal.java:3151)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.getOrCreateCache(IgniteKernal.java:2739)
      at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteAbstractRDD.ensureCache(IgniteAbstractRDD.scala:39)
      at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD$$anonfun$saveValues$1.apply(IgniteRDD.scala:164)
      at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD$$anonfun$saveValues$1.apply(IgniteRDD.scala:161)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:883)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:883)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
      at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
      ... 3 more</pre>
```

Comment: Where do you have this exception? Can you show the whole trace?

Comment: I am execution Spark note book from zeppelin. adding complete stacktrace above

Comment: update: I am still facing this but problem is not consistent, means sometime I face this issue with multiple server node and sometime it works fine, not sure whats causing this issue so far. and **There is no change in code or setup**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the node embedded in the executor process is stopped for some reason while you are still trying to run the job. To my knowledge the only way for this to happen is to stop the executor process. Can this be the case? Is there anything in the log except the trace?

Comment: Executor process did not stop (just to be clear by executor process you meant spark process right ?), and in logs I could not fond anything else apart from  the trace, I got this exception again today and trying to see if anything else can be found

Comment: So far, the pattern I found is that when I start ignite servers by deleting work folder it works otherwise it gives error (but not very sure about this)